# Install codeigniter inside codeigniter installation, what is the disadvantage of it?

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my first question in stackoverflow, and my english is not good enough, im sorry.

what i want to ask is , what is the disadvantage if we install another codeigniter application inside our codeigniter installation?

here is my folder tree :

```
-mywebsite
  -admin
    -application
    -assets
    -system
    -index.php
  -application
  -assets
  -systems
  -index.php
```

and recently i have problem in the hosting with the high CPU time usage in my main installation codeigniter index.php, does this double CI installation cause the problem?

thank you

Comment: If both are not being used at the same time then I don't see a problem.
This is really weird, you shouldn't need to install CI inside CI. This can all be one single application, and the admin folder a part of the application folder, depending on how it's configured.

Comment: Should work, however you maybe have to work with the routes.php to fix some routing problems?

If you don't need a folder structure like this I would create 2 seperate folders and than use a subdomain for the admin

Comment: @Phiter yes, i do think so , but my friend told me like that and earlier there is no problem with the execution, both admin and the main installation work normally.However i got the trouble recently with the high CPU usage.

Comment: @CodeBrauer thank you for your information , i may use that method after this.